# Turn string in array of objects

Tags: jquery, object, multidimensional-array

I have the following data attribute for each item in a list:

```
data-latlng="[{"lat":40.7713024, "lng":-73.9632393}]"
```

I can turn this into an array of objects like

```
arr = $(this).data("latlng");

$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
         coords.push({'details': value});
});
```

and then reference the lat for example:

```
for(var i = 0; i < coords.length; i++){
    console.log(coords[i].details.lat);
}
```

However now I need some extra info, like a title.. but now that its multidimensional I can't reference or access it any more.. Any ideas?!

```
data-latlng="[{title:"Johns place", location:{lat:40.7713024, lng:-73.9632393}}]"

var coords = [
    {title: 'Johns place', location: {lat: 40.7713024, lng: -73.9632393}},
    {title: 'Jacks Loft', location: {lat: 40.7444883, lng: -73.9949465}},
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you have the attribute with location. If you used the following, it would be easier to access the latitude and longitude:

```
data-latlng="[{“title”:"Johns place", “lat”:40.7713024, ”lng“:-73.9632393}]"
```

In any case, below is my proposed solution. Hope it can help.

```js
$('li').each(function() {
arr = $(this).data("details")[0];
/* Not really needed actually  
coords = [];
$.each(arr, function(index, value) {
   coords[index] = value;
});
*/
    $('#title').html(arr.title);
    $('#latitude').html(arr.location.lat);
    $('#longitude').html(arr.location.lng);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li data-details='[{"title":"Johns place", "location":{"lat":40.7713024, "lng":-73.9632393}}]'>Johns Place</li>
</ul>
<div id="title">
</div>
<div id="location">
  <label>Location</label>
  <span id="latitude"></span>
  <span id="longitude"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks mate. How would you ref lat lng in the js if not in a data attr? A separate xml file?

Comment: @Rich Sorry for the late reply. I think I was not clear....my bad. I meant that instead of putting lat and lng within "location", you could put these attributes on their own.

Comment: Btw, I updated the code. The coords array is not really needed, you can just access information directly from the "arr" (whichever suits your needs)

Answer (score 0):

Correct your json string

```
{
    "coords": [{
        "title": "Johns place",
        "location": [{
            "lat": 40.7713024,
            "lng": -73.9632393
        }]
    }, {
        "title": "Johns place",
        "location": [{
            "lat": 40.7713024,
            "lng": -73.9632393
        }]
    }]
}
```

access code

```
var latitude = data.coords.location[0].lat;
console.log('Latitude : ', latitude);

var longitude = data.coords.location[0].lng;
console.log('Longitude : ', longitude);
```